# Отладка Ajax в Django

Tags: ajax, json, django

Пытаюсь выполнить код на сервере через django, но не знаю как отловить ошибку, так как не могу понять, выполняется ли код на сервере и передаются ли туда хоть какие то данные:

views.py

```
def create_strike_view(request):
    message = "jjjj"
    return HttpResponse(message)
```

account_deatails.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="col-xs-6 ">
    <div class="card ">
        {% if account.image %}
          <img src="{{account.image.url}}"  height=500 width=500>
        {% else %}
          <img src="no">
        {% endif %}
            <form method='post' id='test'>
              <input type="hidden" value="video34"/>
              <input type='submit' value='Test button'/>
              <div id='message'>Initial text</div>
            </form>

    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#test").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/ajax/",
          data: {
            'video': $('#test').val() // from form
          },
          success: function () {
            alert ("hhh");
          }
        });
        return false;
      });
    });
</script>
{% endblock content %}
```

urls.py

```
<код выше>    
path('ajax/',create_strike_view,name = "post_strike"),
<код ниже>
```

Как понять выполняется ли код?
Как в последствии его отлаживать?

Comment: можно в "инструменты разработчика" браузера глянуть, что по сети ходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Постараюсь ответить, т.к. сейчас очень часто сталкиваюсь с этим.

1е. как написано в комментарии, необходимо открыть панель разработчика F12 и во вкладке Network найти ваш post-запрос он идет с типом xhr, далее во вкладке Headers внизу вы увидите отправленные данные, в вашем случае ключ 'video'. Там же в Network есть вкладка Responce в которой в случае успеха вы должны увидеть предполагаемое "jjjj". Убедитесь в правильности написания запроса, начните с передачи текстовых данных. загрузка файлов, таких как видео происходит иначе.

2е. Добавьте в ajax обработку ошибки error: это добавит вам информативности. Н-р:

```
success : ... ,
error: function (xhr, status, error) {
    console.log(xhr.responceText);
    #или
    console.log(status, error);
}
```

3е. Не знаю как у вас (возможно данная ошибка была проигнорирована, странно, что вы с ней не столкнулись), но в джанго есть обязательное условие для форм - это защита от подмены вводимых данных, для этого в данном фреймворке используется csrf token. возможно он стоит вашем основном файле html, т.к. ваш пример html кода взят из расширения шаблона ({% extends...). вот мой пример его использования для ajax-запросов:
views.py

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect

@csrf_protect #я использую декоратор на той вьюхе которая требует защиты
def create_strike_view(request):
    message = "jjjj"
    return HttpResponse(message)
```

account_deatails.html

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#test").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var token = '{{csrf_token}}'; #передаем токен из вью

    $.ajax({
      headers: {"X-CSRFToken": token}, #добавляем его в наш запрос
      type: "POST",
      url: "/ajax/",
      data: {
        'video': $('#test').val() // from form
      },
      success: function () {
        alert ("hhh");
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```